# Rasa `RegexEntityExtractor` extracting non entities as entities

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, named-entity-extraction

I was trying to extract user names from input. This is the related training data (I have not provided the entire data since that would bloat the question):

```
nlu:

- intent: greet
  examples: |
    - hey
    - hello
    - hi
    - hello there

- intent: en_name
  examples: |
    - my name is [adarsh](name)
    - name is [suma](name)
    - I am [sourav](name)

- regex: name
  examples: |
    - \w{2,40}
```

```
stories:

- story: Start conversation
  - intent: greet
  - action: utter_greet
  - action: utter_help
  - intent: seek_scheme
  - action: user_info_form
  - active_loop: user_info_form
```

```
rules:

- rule: activate form
  steps:
    - intent: seek_scheme
    - action : user_info_form
    - active_loop: user_info_form

- rule : submit form
  condition:
    - active_loop: user_info_form
  steps:
    - action : user_info_form
    - active_loop: null
    - slot_was_set:
        - requested_slot : null
    - action: utter_submit
    - action: utter_slot_values

- rule : Deviated form path
  condition:
    - active_loop: user_info_form
  steps:
    - intent: bot_challenge
    - action: utter_iamabot
    - action : user_info_form
    - active_loop: user_info_form
```

Here, since I was using regex, I had to add `RegexEntityExtractor` for my pipeline. But after adding it, even "hi" as input is being treated as entity *name*. This is a sample from rasa interactive session:

```
? Your input -> hi
? Is the intent 'greet' correct for '[hi](name)' and are all entities labeled correctly? No
? What intent is it? 1.00 greet
? Please mark the entities using [value](type) notation hi
```

Like this, for any word I provide, it is tagging it to entity *name*. I guess this is because, `RegexEntityExtractor` doesn't account for intents when extracting entity. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think by definition of your `name` regex as `\w{2,40}` any word between 2 and 40 characters will be matched and labelled as an entity.

According to the [documentation](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/components#regexentityextractor), the `RegexEntityExtractor` will use the defined regexes and lookup tables. So if you have a list of names you want to extract, you can add them in a lookup table.

If you want to learn the entities from the training data, you can use trainable extractors like `DIETClassifier` or `CRFEntityExtractor`, or pre-trained models that extract person names such as `SpacyEntityExtractor`.

You can also check out the [Rasa Community Forum](https://forum.rasa.com/) for related threads and suggested pipeline configs.

Comment: I want to build this is Kannada, so there is no Spacy pipeline for it. Can't extract entity based on context of the response?

Comment: In that case you could use `DIETClassifier` to learn the entities based on the training data. For featurizing, you could either use sparse features only (e.g. `CountVectorsFeaturizer`, `LexicalSyntacticFeaturizer`), or try out bytepair embeddings from [rasa-nlu-examples](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-nlu-examples) which I think has a pretrained [Kannada model](https://bpemb.h-its.org/kn/). See [here](https://rasahq.github.io/rasa-nlu-examples/docs/featurizer/bytepair/) for an example how to add it to the NLU pipeline.